# SQL query result cuts down to a single result if AVG function is used

Tags: mysql, sql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this query where I am trying to fetch all my packages from various different vendors. What I want to do is: with each package, I want to place the average rating of the vendor that the package belongs to.

```
SELECT 
    p.id as package_id,
    p.title as package_title,
    p.path as package_image,
    p.packageQuantity as package_quantity,
    p.price as package_price, 
    AVG(r.star_rating) as star_rating 
FROM 
    package as p 
INNER JOIN vendor as v ON v.id = p.vendor_id 
INNER JOIN review as r ON r.vendor = v.id
```

Result with the above query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package_id] => 3
            [package_title] => Simple
            [package_image] => 1f496761e41e3b23d014f5511d591664c94e6390.jpeg
            [package_quantity] => 120 Minutes
            [package_price] => 1236
            [star_rating] => 3.3333333333333335
        )

)
```

The problem is that with the above query I am getting only a single result as compared to all the results that I am getting when I remove the AVG column.

```
SELECT 
    p.id as package_id,
    p.title as package_title,
    p.path as package_image,
    p.packageQuantity as package_quantity,
    p.price as package_price
FROM 
    package as p 
INNER JOIN vendor as v ON v.id = p.vendor_id
```

Result of the query without AVG:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [package_id] => 1
            [package_title] => Normal
            [package_image] => 38fbe34ff595a282a171c6058f40f676bde91665.jpeg
            [package_quantity] => 120 Photos
            [package_price] => 1200
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [package_id] => 2
        [package_title] => Medium Package(Ui)
        [package_image] => 5c9a34123d7e18237641355c59e91b10570e0fed.jpeg
        [package_quantity] => 250 Photos
        [package_price] => 2400
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [package_id] => 3
        [package_title] => Simple
        [package_image] => 1f496761e41e3b23d014f5511d591664c94e6390.jpeg
        [package_quantity] => 120 Minutes
        [package_price] => 1236
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [package_id] => 4
        [package_title] => Better Package
        [package_image] => d0ab8bee318da6b3f1d515835cadcc8669afc0f2.jpeg
        [package_quantity] => 250 Minutes
        [package_price] => 2366
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [package_id] => 5
        [package_title] => Advance Package
        [package_image] => 532b67366f327a17a4cb3e5b194d52950dd58a9b.jpeg
        [package_quantity] => 600 Minutes
        [package_price] => 5698
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [package_id] => 6
        [package_title] => Excellent Package
        [package_image] => 6b7272f9ae03229e41bde2e5933e42b4db061c70.jpeg
        [package_quantity] => 1000 Minutes
        [package_price] => 8966
    )
```

)

I need to be able to fetch all the packages and show it's vendor's average rating on multiple of them, even if it's repetitive.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good opportunity for a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    p.id as package_id,
    p.title as package_title,
    p.path as package_image,
    p.packageQuantity as package_quantity,
    p.price as package_price, 
    (SELECT AVG(r.star_rating) 
     FROM vendor v INNER JOIN
          review r 
          ON r.vendor = v.id
     WHERE  v.id = p.vendor_id
    ) as star_rating 
FROM package p;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`AVG`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) is aggregate function, so you should define a `GROUP BY` column:

```
SELECT 
    p.id as package_id,
    p.title as package_title,
    p.path as package_image,
    p.packageQuantity as package_quantity,
    p.price as package_price, 
    AVG(r.star_rating) as star_rating 
FROM 
    package as p 
INNER JOIN vendor as v ON v.id = p.vendor_id 
INNER JOIN review as r ON r.vendor = v.id
GROUP BY p.id
```